# C#'s IEqualityComparer<TType> similar or alternative in Nest JS Framework with TypeScript

Tags: c#, typescript, nestjs

I'm new to NestJS Framework with TypeScript and my background was .NET Development, I wonder is there any interface or abstract class similar to C#'s IEqualityComparer in Nest JS Framework TypeScript?

Note: I'm trying to develop an SDK (I already had written it in C# and trying to converting into TypeScript) that has an interface that you can use within a generic type. The interface has a method that uses IEqualityComparer.

Best regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: No, there is no direct equality override in Javascript.

Comment: It's actually worth understaning equality in general from a JS perspective, it is VERY different to C#. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness For a start what would you expect this to return `0 == false`?

Comment: Your going to find [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) and [function variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function) pretty alien